# Maximum for $x \in \mathbb{R} $ implies supreme for $x \in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: number-theory

For an assignment I need to prove that $\sup(\mathrm{Re} (\exp(it)z) = |z| $, with $t\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

Therefore I have first proved that $\max(\mathrm{Re} (\exp(it)z) = |z| $, with $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

Now I am strongly wondering if there exists a general result that 
$$
\max(f(t)) \mbox{ with } t \in \mathbb{R} \mbox{ implies } \sup(f(t)) \mbox{ with } t\in \mathbb{Q} 
$$

Comment: If I understood what you are asking I think that statement is true and it follows straight from the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. And as Surb noted $f$ has to be continous.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous it should be ok

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function and let $t^*$ be such that
$$t^* = \max_{t\in \mathbb{R}}f(t),$$
then by density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$ there exists a sequence $(t_n)\subset \mathbb Q$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} t_n = t^*$, and by continuity of $f$ we get $\lim_{n \to \infty}f(t_n) = f(t^*)$. It follows that
$$ \max_{t\in \mathbb{R}}f(t)\geq \sup_{t\in \mathbb{Q}}f(t) \geq\lim_{n \to \infty}f(t_n) =  \max_{t\in \mathbb{R}}f(t).$$
By the way note that for the non continuous function $f(\pi)=1$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x \neq \pi$ the statement don't hold anymore.